USB-Audio no volume unless at 100% sound volume on multiple distros
So basically, whenever I connect a Linux laptop to my docking station which has a builtin speaker I only get audio when the volume is set to 100% (with some small caveats that I explain underneath).
So this occurs on two of my work laptops (one with Fedora 40 and also now with 41, the other with mint 17) and also with my desktop (Fedora 40) and my SteamDeck (SteamOS 3.6).
Now what is interesting here is that I can see, that no matter if I move the volume through the knob on the keyboard, in the os or with the control on the dock itself, if I open ALSAmixer on this device I can see the PCM value is "00" as long as the volume in the OS is set to 0-98, then jumps to 33 when the volume is at 99 and to 100 once set to 100. If I manually adjust the PCM value in the AlsaMixer to let's say 23 then the sound is at the expected volume for that setting, but as soon as I touch the volume in the OS again it jumps to either 0 or 100 again. This setting is consistent on all the devices when looking at it with alsamixer.
Now I do believe that this behavior is in some way related to some setting with alsamixer that it adjusts the wrong value when turning the volume knob or adjusting it through the OS but I can not find that setting again. I think there was a config file somewhere where this could be set but I am not sure anymore. Not that this would help me much on the steam deck (immutable OS) but at least with the other devices I believe I could maybe solve it this way.
Thanks for any help
